# Can we change the input dimensions of image in YoloV7?

Tags: image, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to do inference in yolov7 and changing its default dimensions of **640x640** to **300x300**. Though model weights is trained according to its default dimension. Can we change it , I am changing but it is throwing tensor error ?

```
path = 'image.png'
image = cv2.imread(path)
shape = image.shape
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
shape = image.shape
image = letterbox(image, 300, stride=64, auto=True)[0]
image_ = image.copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same image dimension used during the training process. If you would like to use an image size 300x300, you should first train the model with this dimension. The model accepts only the image dimension that is used during the training process. If you have different image sizes for inference...they should be resized to the input data size of the model before running the inference.